# Handle nested lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I turn a nested list with dict inside into extra columns in a dataframe in Python?

I received information within a dict from an API,

```
{'orders': 
[
{   'orderId': '2838168630', 
    'dateTimeOrderPlaced': '2020-01-22T18:37:29+01:00', 
    'orderItems': [{    'orderItemId':  'BFC0000361764421', 
                        'ean': '234234234234234', 
                        'cancelRequest': False, 
                        'quantity': 1}
                        ]}, 

{   'orderId': '2708182540', 
    'dateTimeOrderPlaced': '2020-01-22T17:45:36+01:00', 
    'orderItems': [{    'orderItemId':  'BFC0000361749496', 
                        'ean': '234234234234234', 
                        'cancelRequest': False, 
                        'quantity': 3}
                        ]}, 

{   'orderId': '2490844970', 
    'dateTimeOrderPlaced': '2019-08-17T14:21:46+02:00', 
    'orderItems': [{    'orderItemId': 'BFC0000287505870', 
                        'ean': '234234234234234', 
                        'cancelRequest': True, 
                        'quantity': 1}
                        ]}
```

which I managed to turn into a simple dataframe by doing this:

```
pd.DataFrame(recieved_data.get('orders'))
```

output:

```
orderId    date    oderItems
1          1-12    [{orderItemId: 'dfs13', 'ean': '34234'}]
2          etc.
...
```

I would like to have something like this

```
orderId    date    oderItemId    ean
1          1-12    dfs13         34234
2          etc.
...
```

I already tried to single out the orderItems column with Iloc and than turn it into a list so I can then try to extract the values again. However I than still end up with a list which I need to extract another list from, which has the dict in it.

Comment: Why not unnest it all before throwing it in a dataframe?

Comment: I tried using the json_normalize methode as well early on, but I received an error when I tried that the data I used was a dict, so I went on trying to find a method with dicts. Maybe i did something wrong with however

Comment: Please post the data as received. This should solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679381/pandas-how-to-load-data-from-nested-dictionary-into-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
# Load the dataframe as you have already done.

temp_df = df['orderItems'].apply(pd.Series)

# concat the temp_df and original df

final_df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])

# drop columns if required
```

Hope it works for you.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

By combining the answers on this question I reached my end goal. I did the following:

```
#unlist the orderItems column
temp_df = df['orderItems'].apply(pd.Series)

#Put items in orderItems into seperate columns
temp_df_json = json_normalize(temp_df[0])

#Join the tables
final_df = df.join(temp_df_json)

#Drop the old orderItems column for a clean table
final_df = final_df.drop(["orderItems"], axis=1)
```

Also, instead of .concat() I applied .join() to join both tables based on the existing index.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, you are receiving a json from the API, so you can try to use the function `json_normalize`.
Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
# DataFrame initialization
df = pd.DataFrame({"orderId": [1], "date": ["1-12"], "oderItems": [{ 'orderItemId': 'dfs13', 'ean': '34234'}]})

# Serializing inner dict
sub_df = json_normalize(df["oderItems"])

# Dropping the unserialized column
df = df.drop(["oderItems"], axis=1)

# joining both dataframes.
df.join(sub_df)
```

So the output is:

```
    orderId date    ean     orderItemId
0   1       1-12    34234   dfs13
```

Comment: Thanks! When I use your code I get the same output. However when I try to use de data received from the API I get the following error: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @NielsvanLeeuwen Always share the entire error message.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 5 sub_df = json_normalize(df["orderItems"])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in <genexpr>(.0
--> 258         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I believe it's due to the fact that the dicts in orderItems are placed within lists. That's what I initially asked as well, how to turn a nested list with a dict inside into a dataframe.